# Convert PHP to Ruby (On Rails)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    $fromDateTS = strtotime($start_date);
    $toDateTS = strtotime($end_date);

    for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) 
    {
        $currentDateStr = date("Y-m-d",$currentDateTS);
    }
```

How would I convert this php to ruby. There doesn't seem to be a for loop in ruby that is similar to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions for this. You can do this for instance:

```
from_start_date_ts = Time.parse(start_date)
to_date_ts = Time.parse(end_date)
current_date_ts = from_start_date_ts
while current_date_ts < to_date_ts
  current_date_ts += 1.day
  current_date_str = current_date_ts.strftime("%D")
end
```

I haven't tested it so it might not work as it is but it is more to show you one possible syntax for a loop in Ruby. Note that you can use while in different ways:

```
while [condition]
 # do something
end


begin
 # do something
end while [condition]
```

You can also use the loop syntax:

```
loop do
  # do something
  break if [condition]
end
```

Or the until loop:

```
until current_date_ts > to_date_ts
  current_date_ts += 1.day
  current_date_str = current_date_ts.strftime("%D")
end
```

There are more :)

Comment: You could also do "current_date_ts += 1.day" and use "current_date_ts.strftime(format string)" to format it as well :)

Comment: while you're at it, don't forget about the "until" loop... just 'cause it reads so nice

Answer (score 1):

I would code it this way:

```
from_start_date_ts = start_date.to_date
to_date_ts = end_date.to_date
from_start_date_ts.step(to_date_ts, 1.day).to_a.map{ |step_date| current_date_str = step_date.to_s }
```

This gives you back an array of step_date strings.